# Sqlalchemy query to csv

Tags: python, csv, sqlalchemy

I'm making the following query:

```
def getAllUserAutority(self):
    #usuarios_con_autoridad = tb_twitter_user.objects.filter(
    #   i_user_follower_count__gt = 1).filter(
    #       i_user_autority__gt = 1).filter(
    #           i_coun_id = 1)
    autoridades = tb_twitter_user.objects.filter(
        i_user_follower_count__gt = 1).filter(
            i_user_autority__gt = 1).filter(
                i_coun_id = 1)

    with open('/home/omar/Escritorio', "wb") as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        for line in autoridades:
            writer.writerow(line)
```

But it's not saving the table results as CSV in the path `/home/omar/Escritorio`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `csv.writer.writerow()` expects you to pass it an argument that's a sequence (like a `list` or `tuple`), which is probably why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up doing this:

```
def getAllUsersAutority(self):
        autoridades = tb_twitter_user.objects.filter(i_user_follower_count__gte = 2000).filter(i_user_autority__gte = 1).filter(i_coun_id = 1)



        with open('usuarios.csv', "w", newline='') as csv_file:
            writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=' ',quotechar='|',quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
            for line in list(autoridades):
                line.v_user_location = re.sub(',', '', line.v_user_location)
                line.v_user_location = re.sub('|', '', line.v_user_location)
                line.v_user_location = re.sub(' ', '', line.v_user_location)
                writer.writerow([line.v_user_screen_name, line.i_coun_id, line.v_user_location, line.i_user_follower_count, line.i_user_autority])


        return autoridades
```